# In OpenCL, how can __local memory be faster when work-group sizes aren't part of the architecture?

Tags: memory, opencl, gpgpu

Apologies for my naiveté if this question is silly, I'm new to GPGPU programming.

My question is, since the architecture of the device can't change, how is it that __local memory can be optimized for access by items only in the local work-group, when it's the user that chooses the work-group size (subject to divisibility)?

Answer (score 4):

Local memory is usually attached to a certain cluster of execution units in GPU hardware. Work group size is indeed chosen by the client application, but the OpenCL implementation will impose a limit. Your application needs to query this via `clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo()` using the `CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` parameter name.

There's some flexibility in work group size because most GPUs are designed so multiple threads of execution can be scheduled to run on a single execution unit. (A form of [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading).) Note also that the scheduled threads don't even need to be in the same work group, so if for example a GPU has 64 processors in a cluster, and supports 4-way SMT on each processor, those 256 threads could be from 1, 2, or 4, or possibly even 8 or 16 work groups, depending on hardware and compiler capabilities.

Some GPUs' processors also use vector registers and instructions internally, so threads don't map 1:1 to OpenCL work items - one processor might handle 4 work items at once, for example.

Ultimately though, a work-group must fit onto the cluster of processors that is attached to one chunk of local memory; so you've got local memory size and maximum number of threads that can be scheduled on one cluster influencing the maximum work group size.

In general, try to minimise the amount of local memory your work group uses so that the OpenCL implementation has the maximum flexibility for scheduling work groups. (But definitely do use local memory when it helps performance! Just use as little of it as possible.)